# Invoking non template function from template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, member-functions

I am trying to call a member function from a member template function but it
complains about not having overloads for a member function. How do I fix it?
Below is the test code.

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void foo(int i, T param)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1:
            fun(param);
            break;
        case 2:
            bar(param);
        }
    }
    void fun(string p)
    {
        std::cout << "string: " << p << std::endl;
    }
    void bar(double p)
    {
        std::cout << "double: " << p << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    t.foo(1, "hello");
    t.foo(2, 100.0);
    return 0;
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'Test::fun(double&)'

Comment: I think you're confused as to what templates do. They literally compile as if you were to replace every 'T' with whatever you wrote. So it also tries to call a `fun` that takes a double. even though during runtime it is not called. As you pass 2 to the function. That error should be pointing to `fun(param);`. Try making a non-template `foo` and replace all T's with double. What error would you expect the compiler gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to call `fun` or `bar` depends on `param` parameter of `foo`. If you are using c++17 you can use `if constexpr` to do that:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T param)
    {
        if constexpr (is_same_v<T,string> || is_same_v<T,const char*>)
            fun(param);
        else if (is_same_v<T,double>)
            bar(param);
    }

    void fun(string p)
    {
        std::cout << "string: " << p << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(double p)
    {
        std::cout << "double: " << p << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    t.foo("hello");
    t.foo(100.0);
    return 0;
}
```

and `int i` parameter of `foo` here is no needed, you decide which `fun`/`bar` is called based on `param` type.

Comment: Kind of beats the purpose of overloads

Answer (score 1):

For a given type `typename T` the function template can be instantiated only if every statement in the function body are valid. In particular, this includes both your `fun` and `bar` calls.

To fix it, you need to fix the design first. From what perspires from your code sample, I think you want something akin to:

```
void foo(double param)
{
    bar(param);
}

void foo(string param)
{
    fun(param);
}
```